# JSON.parse throws syntax error when trying to parse escaped double quote

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing

I can't seem to figure out Why this happens. I have an Array that I echo as a Json string into a dynamically created JavaScript tag in my page.

Here's the PHP code :

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">var Lang = \'';
echo str_replace('\'', '\\\'', json_encode($this->Lang));
echo '\';Lang = JSON.parse(Lang);</script>';
```

But when JavaScript is going to Parse the string, I get this Error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in
>   object at line 1 column 162 of the JSON data

This usually means that I have a Syntax error in my Json string, But I can't find this syntax error.

Here is what this script tag looks like in Browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var Lang = '{"Code":"en","Layout":"LtR","Error_NoPassword":"Password is Required","Error_NoUsername":"Username is Required","Header_Notification_Comment":"[A] commented on \"[O]\"","Header_Notification_Follow":"[A] is now following \"[O]\"","Header_Notification_Like":"[A] liked \"[O]\"","Header_Notification_Message":"[A] sent you a message.","PLogin_Login_Fail":"Login failed","PLogin_Login_ForgotLink":"Click here if you forgot your password !","PLogin_Multiverse_Description_Text":"Multiverse is an application developed for Story writers of Comics, Games, Movies, Novels and etc. This application uses \"Snowflake Method\" to make things easier for the author.","PLogin_Multiverse_Description_Title":"What is Multiverse ?","PLogin_ResetPassword_Title":"Reset Password","PLogin_ResetPassword_Description":"Enter the email address you use on Multiverse. Your email must have been verified after you signed up. If you didn\'t verify your email address, We\'re afraid there\'s nothing we can do at this point.","PLogin_ResetPassword_MailSent":"In case you have entered your email address correctly, And it is verified, Then an email was sent to your address containing a single-use link to reset your password.","PLogin_SrcError_Account":"In order to have an account of your own, You need to sign up first !","PLogin_SrcError_Edit":"In order to create your own content, You need to create an account first !","PLogin_SrcError_People":"In order to interact with other people on Multiverse, You need to create an account first !","PLogin_Signup_UsernameWillBe":"Your username will be : ","Signup_Fail_Captcha":"Captcha Failed !","Signup_Fail_Email":"Incorrect email address","Signup_Fail_Password":"It is recommended for password to be 8 or more characters","Signup_Fail_Unknown":"Registration failed for unknown reason","Signup_Fail_UsernameTaken":"Username is already taken","Signup_Fail_UsernameInvalid":"Username is Invalid.","Signup_Fail_Realname":"Enter your Name","Signup_Title":"Become an Author now","Signup_ExploreButton":"Explore as Guest !","UniExp_Info_IsPublic":"Public","UniExp_Info_Description":"Description","UniExp_Info_Language":"Language","UniExp_SelectedInfo_NoTimeline":"No Timeline Selected","UniExp_SelectedInfo_NoStory":"No Story Selected","Word_Account":"Account","Word_Act":"Act","Word_Character":"Character","Word_ContactUs":"Contact Us","Word_Editors":"Editors","Word_EmailAddress":"Email Address","Word_Explore":"Explore","Word_ID":"ID","Word_License":"License","Word_Login":"Log In","Word_Logout":"Sign Out","Word_MobileVersion":"Mobile Version","Word_MyUniverses":"My Universes","Word_Name":"Name","Word_No":"No","Word_Owner":"Owner","Word_Part":"Part","Word_Password":"Password","Word_People":"People","Word_Plot":"Plot","Word_Realname":"Real Name","Word_Scene":"Scene","Word_Search":"Search","Word_Select":"Select","Word_Signup":"Sign up","Word_Story":"Story","Word_Timeline":"Timeline","Word_Unknown":"Unknown","Word_Universe":"Universe","Word_Username":"Username","Word_You":"You","Word_Yes":"Yes"}';Lang = JSON.parse(Lang);</script>
```

For the sake of readability, I put a PRETTY_PRINT version of my Json string here:

```
{
"Code": "en",
"Layout": "LtR",
"Error_NoPassword": "Password is Required",
"Error_NoUsername": "Username is Required",
"Header_Notification_Comment": "[A] commented on \"[O]\"",
"Header_Notification_Follow": "[A] is now following \"[O]\"",
"Header_Notification_Like": "[A] liked \"[O]\"",
"Header_Notification_Message": "[A] sent you a message.",
"PLogin_Login_Fail": "Login failed",
"PLogin_Login_ForgotLink": "Click here if you forgot your password !",
"PLogin_Multiverse_Description_Text": "Multiverse is an application developed for Story writers of Comics, Games, Movies, Novels and etc. This application uses \"Snowflake Method\" to make things easier for the author.",
"PLogin_Multiverse_Description_Title": "What is Multiverse ?",
"PLogin_ResetPassword_Title": "Reset Password",
"PLogin_ResetPassword_Description": "Enter the email address you use on Multiverse. Your email must have been verified after you signed up. If you didn\'t verify your email address, We\'re afraid there\'s nothing we can do at this point.",
"PLogin_ResetPassword_MailSent": "In case you have entered your email address correctly, And it is verified, Then an email was sent to your address containing a single-use link to reset your password.",
"PLogin_SrcError_Account": "In order to have an account of your own, You need to sign up first !",
"PLogin_SrcError_Edit": "In order to create your own content, You need to create an account first !",
"PLogin_SrcError_People": "In order to interact with other people on Multiverse, You need to create an account first !",
"PLogin_Signup_UsernameWillBe": "Your username will be : ",
"Signup_Fail_Captcha": "Captcha Failed !",
"Signup_Fail_Email": "Incorrect email address",
"Signup_Fail_Password": "It is recommended for password to be 8 or more characters",
"Signup_Fail_Unknown": "Registration failed for unknown reason",
"Signup_Fail_UsernameTaken": "Username is already taken",
"Signup_Fail_UsernameInvalid": "Username is Invalid.",
"Signup_Fail_Realname": "Enter your Name",
"Signup_Title": "Become an Author now",
"Signup_ExploreButton": "Explore as Guest !",
"UniExp_Info_IsPublic": "Public",
"UniExp_Info_Description": "Description",
"UniExp_Info_Language": "Language",
"UniExp_SelectedInfo_NoTimeline": "No Timeline Selected",
"UniExp_SelectedInfo_NoStory": "No Story Selected",
"Word_Account": "Account",
"Word_Act": "Act",
"Word_Character": "Character",
"Word_ContactUs": "Contact Us",
"Word_Editors": "Editors",
"Word_EmailAddress": "Email Address",
"Word_Explore": "Explore",
"Word_ID": "ID",
"Word_License": "License",
"Word_Login": "Log In",
"Word_Logout": "Sign Out",
"Word_MobileVersion": "Mobile Version",
"Word_MyUniverses": "My Universes",
"Word_Name": "Name",
"Word_No": "No",
"Word_Owner": "Owner",
"Word_Part": "Part",
"Word_Password": "Password",
"Word_People": "People",
"Word_Plot": "Plot",
"Word_Realname": "Real Name",
"Word_Scene": "Scene",
"Word_Search": "Search",
"Word_Select": "Select",
"Word_Signup": "Sign up",
"Word_Story": "Story",
"Word_Timeline": "Timeline",
"Word_Unknown": "Unknown",
"Word_Universe": "Universe",
"Word_Username": "Username",
"Word_You": "You",
"Word_Yes": "Yes"
}
```

As mentioned in the error, Column 162 of my Json data is the first occurrence of an escaped double quote (\"), But it there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that!

Specially when PHP's own function (json_encode) gave me that!

What is the problem here?

(My browser is Firefox Quantum on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 ...)

Comment: why do you have echo `str_replace` ?  try removing it and see it any changes happen

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Be sure to run your JSON through a validator (say, http://jsonlint.com) before posting. Specifically, `\'` is not a valid escape sequence in JSON (it's also pointless, just use `'`). More: http://json.org/

Comment: @azjezz : `str_replace` is because I have single quotes in my HTML, And I need to escape those before giving them to Javascript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : I just found the problem and wrote an answer. And there's nothing wrong with `\'`, Actually it will be `'` in JSon.

Comment: I Wonder Why do people give a lot of Downvotes to my question !

Comment: you don't have to set json as string ! you can do `var lang = <?= json_encode($var); ?>;`

Comment: @Dante: Again: It's invalid. I suggest actually reading the linked page. Some parsers will tolerate it, which is not the same thing as it being valid. (In contrast: `\'` is a perfectly valid escape sequence in *JavaScript* strings.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Right. I completely changed my method due to Lawrence Cherone's answer. I simply echo the output of `json_encode` in front of `var Lang = ` in my javascript and it becomes an object when Browser parses the HTML ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), **you don't need to escape anything**, it will generate valid json. You also don't need to add it as a string and then parse it again with javascript.

So for example you would do:

```
<?php
// a mock of your object
$_this = new class {
    public $Code = 'en';
};

echo sprintf(
    '<script type="text/javascript">var Lang=%s;</script>', 
    json_encode($_this)
);
```

The result will look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var Lang={"Code":"en"};</script>
```

https://3v4l.org/qQunD

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** *Lawrence Cherone's answer is Better !*

Found the answer ...
The escaped double quote was in HTML, So it was a \" in HTML but HTML gave it to Javascript and Javascript consumed that backslash.
Therefore in Javascript it's a doublequote without backslash (as "). But JSon needs the backslash to interpret the " as a part of the Value.

**Solution :**
I added another *str_replace* in PHP and replaces all my (\") strings to (\\") so that it will have an Additional backslash in the end for JSon.

New (Correct) PHP :

```
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">var Lang = \'';
    $JSN = str_replace('\'', '\\\'', json_encode($this->Lang));
    $JSN = str_replace('\"', '\\\"',$JSN);
    echo $JSN;
    echo '\';Lang = JSON.parse(Lang);</script>';
```